# App to make hotspot from mobile that sends and receives data from other device and send a website without going directly through the other device?

Tags: android, web-apps, javascript, software-development, html

I have a device with an IP that cannot receive any websites (I made a website and forgot it and I don't want to reset the device). So, now I want an app that is capable of receiving data from my device in a website like 192.168.x.x and then process this data and send a working copy of the website to my device on the same tab.

Sorry for my expressing it in a non-easy way. Note: The two devices are running Android.

I want the app to be on the first device as an embedded browser in a site and in the mobile that made the hotspot all the data is being processed like the website its cache and every thing but the other device just sees a working embeded browser in a site where its link is (192.168.x.x).

Comment: Thanks – now it's on-topic, but unclear what you are looking for. Did you simply store the data from one website on one of those devices? Or is the webserver running on it? Shall it just send some static files – or is there something needed to process "dynamic stuff" first?

Comment: I want it to be on the first device as an embeded brower in a site and in the mobile that mad the hotspot all the data is being processed like the website its cache and every thing but the other device just sees a working embeded browser in a site where its link is (192.168.x.x)

Comment: Do I understand correctly you're asking for a [proxy](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_proxy) (link goes to my list of proxy apps)?

Comment: Sth like that. But other that you write url like google I want the app that made the hotspot make( sth like a login page) but other than writing a username and password your write a link and the mobile process this data and download the website then send it back to the device and so on but from a wesite like(192.168.x.x )